# How to use hibernate lucene search for entity which have many to one relation

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate lucene for searching. Now I want to search with an entity which has a many to one relation

I have two class one is `catalogueBase` and another one is `Subject`, here subject has a many-to-one relation (it is one sided relation)

catalogueBase.java class :

```java
@Indexed
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="catalogueBase")
public class CatalogueBase extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    // some entities
    // ...
    private Subject subject; 

    // setter and get methods 
    // ...

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject1", insertable = true, updatable=true, nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty
    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
```

Subject.java (what ever i want to search regarding subject it will be stored in description column) :

```java
@Indexed
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="subject")
public class Subject implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String description;

    // ...
    @Column(name = "subjectname", nullable = false, length = 150)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // ....
}
```

this is my DAO method :

```java
private List<CatalogueBase> searchTitle(String queryString) throws InterruptedException {
    Session session = getSession();
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session); 
    fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = null;
    List<CatalogueBase> resultList = null;
    try{
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CatalogueBase.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("title","subject").matching(queryString).createQuery();     
        fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CatalogueBase.class);

        List<CatalogueBase> contactList = fullTextQuery.list();

        resultList = new ArrayList<CatalogueBase>();;

        for (CatalogueBase catalogueBase : contactList) {
            catalogueBase.setNoOfCopiesBooks(getCopydetailsCount(catalogueBase.getId()));
            catalogueBase.setIssuedCount(getIssuedCount(catalogueBase.getId()));
            resultList.add(catalogueBase);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

But it's giving an error like: `SearchException: Unable to find field subject in com.easylib.elibrary.model.CatalogueBase`

And I did something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852557/how-to-search-in-related-entity-hibernate-search), but error was the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got solution.

I will just post code...

```java
@Indexed  // must
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="subject")
public class Subject implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String description;

    @ContainedIn   // must
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name = "subjectname", nullable = false, length = 150)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

In catalogue:

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject1", insertable = true, updatable=true, nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty
    @IndexedEmbedded   // must
    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
```

And in the DAO, it must be:

```java
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("subject.description").matching(queryString).createQuery();
```